# How to build a hash table with multiple workers, but without shared memory

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable, distributed

I would like to create a hash table with many (potentially hundreds) workers (computational entities, you could also call them nodes if you like). The goal is to speed up the creation of a large hash table by utilizing concurrency. One approach to how to do this would be **Radix** partitioning (compare paper "Optimizing Main-Memory Join on Modern Hardware"). To my understanding, this approach needs shared memory, meaning all workers can write their results to the same memory. Here this is not the case. **Each worker has their own memory**.

**Questions:** How would I create a (potentially big) hash table in this setup? What do you think about my ideas?

**Variables:**

**d** - The dataset from which to build the hash table **h(d)**

**P** - The set of all partitions in **d**, aka. the chunks of data that each worker works with. A single partition in **P** is called **p**.

**n** - The number of partitions in **P**, which is equal to the number of workers, since each worker gets one **p**.

**h(p)** - A single hash table, aka the hash table that was build from **p**.

**h(d)** - The resulting hash table, which is the sum of the individual hash tables **h(p)**.

**k** - number of parts when splitting up key range of the hash function **h**.

**Idea 1:**

Simple approach: Each worker gets a partition **p**, builds a hash-table from it and writes it to her own memory.

**Advantage 1**: Simple

**Drawback 1:** If **n** is large and you want to look up a value in **h(d)**, you will have to check **n** different hash tables. The worst case would be that **n** is equal to the number of all elements in **d**. If that is the case you would basically do a sequential scan over **d**.

**Improvement 1:** To improve on **Idea 1**, we could use [Bloom Filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). Bloom filters basically tell us if a hash is in a **h(p)** (false positives are possible, false negatives are impossible). If we are lucky, we can avoid scanning many of the **h(p)** s to look up a key.

**Idea 2:**

Split up the key range of the hash function into **k** parts. You now need **n * k** workers. Each worker processes a **p**, but only cares for the keys that map to her part of the key range. We can now try to keep **n** low, meaning that the size of **p**  will be big, which is okay since the resulting **h(p)** will still be small since each **h(p)** only contains on average **1/k** of the number of elements in **p**.

**Advantage:** Let`s say we keep **n** very small, e.g. **n = 3**, but we use a high **k**. We can still distribute the work across many workers since the number of workers is **n * k**. To look up a key we would only have to check 3 different hash tables, which is nice. Since we know to which range our key maps, we can directly check that range within each **h(p)**.

**Drawback 2:** Potential overhead, since each worker processes a lot of data (big **p**), but only actually uses a small part of it (average 1/k). I guess that this approach would be slower than **idea 1**, since **p** is bigger.

**EDIT:**

The workers will send the created tables **h(p)** to one worker, who will use all **h(p)** s aka. **h(d)** to look up a key. In the end the goal here is to speed up the building phase of the hash table, while still having good speed during the probing phase.

Comment: Please explain how you want to access the **h(d)** table. I can only try to guess that from your Ideas but I am not sure I understand you correctly.

Comment: Thank you @Vroomfondel for the comment. You are right, I should have mentioned that

Comment: It looks like you're reinventing an existing wheel - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table

Comment: Thank you for the hint @Malt I will read this tomorrow and come back to you. Maybe you are right. I mean would be good if you are right, then I do not have to do the extra work

Comment: Thank you @Malt for the advice, but distributed hash tables (DHTs) are not what I am looking for: DHTs provide a service to a 3rd party, by splitting up values among nodes, based on h(key) of those values (similar to partitioning in distributed DBs). What I need is a normal HT. My workers are generic compute nodes and will not be available to look up values after they are done with this task, since they will be busy doing other stuff. So, I am really just looking for a way to distribute the building phase of a HT with the given architecture.

Comment: Are you sure that this solution, namely to create n small hash tables and transmit them (which type of link?) to one single node and store them there in n slots, will under an amortized examination turn out that much faster? In the end you are using a hash table bcs. access is O(1) and access is all that is needed for construction, i.e. reading, sending and then writing to memory should not be substantially faster than contstructing from scratch unless your hash function is insanely complex.

Comment: No, I am not sure. I do have these workers, though and I have a lot of data to process, so I would like to put them to use

Comment: Rather than building h(p) completely and sending them to build h(d), could the workers calculate each hashkey and send/queue batches of hashkeys  to the main h(d) ?  I suspect the cost of merging many h(p) will be higher than simply inserting immediately.  If not, I can see some ways you could do this as asked, but it would only be quicker for certain characteristics of the input data (eg large value to be hashed, slow hashing function, etc)